# Update a document numeric field to value 0 not working

Tags: mongodb, go

I have a Go function that updates a MongoDB document with a new value and it works with any value but 0. And I don't understand why. It returns a ModifiedCount of 0.
So for example, I can update the field "price" from 75 to 20. But it won't update it from 75 to 0. The important parts look like this:

```
type Car struct {
    ID             primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id,omitempty" `
    Price          float64            `json:"price" form:"price" bson:"price,omitempty"`
}
...
updateResult, err := c.UpdateOne(ctx, filter, bson.M{"$set": update}, options)
```

where:

filter:

```
 {ObjectID("5f1aa6da68ac05d7863e9b41")}
```

and update:

```
 {ObjectID("5f1aa6da68ac05d7863e9b41") 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, but I think it's due to the `omitempty` rule on your bson, since `nil` can't be a valid value for float, the `0` value omit your field. More explanation [here](https://www.sohamkamani.com/golang/2018-07-19-golang-omitempty/). If that field can be set as null value, I recommend you use [this approach](https://medium.com/aubergine-solutions/how-i-handled-null-possible-values-from-database-rows-in-golang-521fb0ee267).

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with omitempty (and I already tried). As I said, this functions work for any other value. So im never passing a Price value to the filter object and still this is working. Is only when setting a value 0 instead of anything else in the update object when this doesnt work. And if im not mistaken, 0 is not considered nil for a numeric field.